# How to read mail from particular user and between particular intervals(in days) in java using javax?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have used following line of code,

```
SearchTerm term = null;
    if (fromAddress != null) {
        FromStringTerm fromTerm = new FromStringTerm(fromAddress);
       term = fromTerm;
      }
```

...

```
  Session session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props, null);
    Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);
    store.connect();
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message messages[] = inbox.search(term);
```

The above code is not server my purpose. Search hangs while executing.

Anyone has any alternative??

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think you might have better luck with "IMAP".

Comment: Right.  With POP3, all searching is done by downloading the messages to your machine and running the search there.  With IMAP, the server does the work of search and returns the result.  Also, you can create a more complex search term using AndTerm.